# Unable to UPSERT records in Apache Phoenix through PHP

Tags: php, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to select and `UPSERT` value in [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/) from `PHP` Classes. I am able to `select` using `php curl` to query server which is installed on port `8765` , like I have share in example. 
Similarly I am trying to insert data`(UPSERT)` in Phoenix using PHP Curl. Its giving me response but data not inserting.

### PHP

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:8765/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array();
// For Select.
//$headers[] = 'request: {"request":"prepareAndExecute","connectionId":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","sql":"select * from BLOG.POST"}';

// For Upsert.
$headers[] = 'request: {"request":"prepareAndExecute","connectionId":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","sql":"UPSERT INTO BLOG.POST (POST_ID,TITLE,CONTENT) values (\'aa11111\',\'Test Title\',\'this is test post content\')"}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

### Output:

```
 {"response":"Service$ExecuteResponse","results":[{"response":"resultSet","connectionId":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","statementId":1164383384,"ownStatement":false,"signature":null,"firstFrame":null,"updateCount":1}]}
```

So can anyone suggest me is there anything wrong in my approach? or any other ways to connect Apache phoenix through php classes.

Comment: What is an `UPSERT`? Do you mean `INSERT`

Comment: So have you changed it from `UPSERT` to `INSERT` in the query you pass to the server?

Comment: No, As I am referring to [official document](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html) where I found I need to use `UPSERT` to insert data. Please Suggest me, Do I need to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just need to following things in your hbase configration file.

phoenix.connection.autoCommit=true to hbase-site.xml